# Limiting file size before submit through Dynamic Acrton in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want to create a Dynamic Action to check file size of File Browser field. I can not put validation I have to implement this through Dynamic Action. Please help here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to check the size of a file before a user upload it inside an apex application. That does not look to me like a dynamic action. Why you cannot use validations ?

Anyway, I would have a look at this interesting plugin : [apex file size plugin](https://github.com/Dani3lSun/apex-plugin-filesizechecker)

If you are interested, I know how to do it by using PL/SQL against apex_application_temp_files. In my case the user uploads the file using a file browser, then press upload, which triggers a PL/SQL process. The PLSQL program returns an error if the size is greater than 10M. Let me know if this suits you.

Correction: Actually the plugin I mentioned before can be used in a dynamic action.

- Continuation

As I said before, I would use a piece of PL/SQL code over the apex_application_temp_files table. That table is maintained automatically by Apex. In my application I have the following code associated to the button which Upload the files. Once the user selects the file he/she wants to upload, the process triggers the procedure to check several aspects ( in my case I check that is a csv file and also the size )

```
procedure ValidateFiles (p_file_name in varchar2, p_file_type in varchar2) is 
v_blob blob;
blob_length integer;
v_mime_type varchar2(2000);
vlimitsize pls_integer := XXXXXXX -- your limit here
--
begin 
SELECT BLOB_CONTENT, 
        DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(blob_content), 
        mime_type, 
        INTO v_blob,blob_length,v_mime_type
FROM apex_application_temp_files
WHERE name = p_file_name;

if upper(v_mime_type) <> 'TEXT/COMMA-SEPARATED-VALUES' then
  raise_application_error(-20000, 'Wrong extension file, expected: 
text/comma-separated-values.');
end if;
-- debug apex messages
apex_debug.message('blob length: %s', blob_length);
--
if blob_length > vlimitsize 
then
  raise_application_error(-20000, 'File is greater than the limit allowed');
end if;
end;
```

end ValidateFiles;

Comment: @Anshul Ayushya did you check it, or do you need to build a PL/SQL package for doing the same ?

Comment: Thanks for replying Roberto... 
Why you cannot use validations ? I cannot use validation because there are multiple file browser fields with other items too. so when validation fires for any reason file goes off from browser and rest details remains on it.

This plug in shows an unsupported file error. Please let me know if can put a code on change of file browser field. If yes, please explain how will it be done then.
More over I saw the plugin working on sample application link provided is what for which I am looking.

Comment: Hi @AnshulAyushya . I will send you Monday a code in PL/SQL I am using for this purpose which works.